# Log likelihood improves with addition of a nonsignificant variable

Tags: regression, model-selection, linear-model, likelihood

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64227/improvements-in-aic-when-adding-a-variable-that-is-not-close-to-signficant/64401#64401) I asked about changes to AIC when adding a variable. It turns out to be partly due to the way SAS figures AIC.

However, I now have two models where the log likelihood improves a lot:

This code

```
title 'Test - only forced';
ods select FitStatistics SolutionF;
proc mixed data = menfat.data method = ml;
 class &classvar;
 model  bmd_legneck_change_per_year = &bmddef bmdlegneck_1/solution;
run;
```

had  -2LL of 1631.9

adding one variable with this code

```
title 'Test - add packyrs';
ods select FitStatistics SolutionF;
proc mixed data = menfat.data method = ml;
 class &classvar;
 model  bmd_legneck_change_per_year = &bmddef packyrs bmdlegneck_1/solution;
run;
```

had a -2LL of 1607.6 (which is highly significant difference of 24.3 on 1 df) but the parameter estimate for packyrs was 0.0016 with an SE of 0.005 and a p of 0.77.

Could this be due to improvement of the fit of other variables in the model?

EDIT: Responding to Macro; the model is a linear regression where the dependent variable is a change per year of a physical quality (bone density) and the independent variables are a mix of yes/no variables and continuous ones.

Comment: Ok a few other questions: 1) Are there any random effects in this model? 2) Does the `packyrs` variable have any missing data? 3) Any chance of a simulated example that exhibits this behavior? It may increase the chance of hunting down this issue if we had some data to tinker with.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks.  Number 2 is it. There was missing data for packyrs that was not missing for other variables. When I reran with just the complete data, the -2LL didn't change.

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted an answer below. BTW, your twitter page (@peterflom) is hilarious.

Comment: Glad you like it! I also have @PeterFlomStat, which is much less funny :-).  Who are you there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that there was missing data in the predictor you added to your model, making the log-likelihoods on different scales and therefore not comparable. This is a very insidious problem sometimes because most software, by default, removes those cases silently and leaves you to figure out what happened (smh..) and is one most analysts will run into eventually. I know in `R` there is an argument called `na.action` that you can pass to GLMs to control exactly what it does with missing (`NA`) values but I'm not sure how to control this in SAS.

Often times this issue is only detected after observing odd behavior in the log-likelihood, such as wild discrepancies between the Wald-based and the LRT-based $p$-values, as you saw here. Related to this, while there is likely to be *some* differences between the Wald and LRT-based inference, there shouldn't be a ton, especially for larger sample sizes, since the two are asymptotically equivalent.

Comment: Macro, what do you mean by saying that the log-likelihoods are on different scales? I have difficulties in understanding that.

Comment: If you have $n$ independent units observed, then the log likelihood is a sum over $n$ terms and so its value scales with $n$. For example, the maximized log-likelihood from a sample of $n > m$ is likely to be a larger (negative) number than the maximized log-likelihood from a sample size of $m$ because of this scaling. Therefore comparing the maximized log-likelihood from the larger sample with that from the smaller sample (in this case, where the missing values have been excluded) does not give a meaningful comparison. That's all I really meant.

Comment: Thanks very much for these explanations, it's much clearer now.

Comment: +1 Nice catch.  Thanks for turning your comment into an answer.  The relationship between the two log-likelihoods based on different subsets of the data is not generally predictable: in some cases, most data have positive log likelihoods, so including additional records increases the maximum (*caeteris paribus*); in many cases, most data have negative log likelihoods and including extra records decreases the maximum. One moral of this experience is that in looking at output it always pays to review even the very simplest summary statistics, such as data *counts*.